# Can not show inline image in org file: "No images to display inline"

Tags: org-mode, images

Linux Mint 19.3

Emacs 26.3

Here is my org file:

```
* TODO Test insert image
  Test this
  #+CAPTION: This is the caption for the next figure link (or table)
  #+NAME:   Deepspace
  [[KLOCKA6.JPG]]
    
* TODO Hello from this 
  Hello
```

This org file is in the same folder as image `KLOCKA6.JPG`.

I want to show the image as an inline image in the org file.

I use the command `org-toggle-inline-images` but I get an error  message:

```
No images to display inline
```

How do I display the file as an inline image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a path: `[[./KLOCKA6.JPG]]`, otherwise the link is not recognized as a file link. Alternatively, you can make sure that it *is* recognized as a file link if you write it explicitly as `[[file:KLOCKA6.JPG]]`. See [External links](https://orgmode.org/manual/External-Links.html#External-Links).

Comment: Not show image inside org file. Now I get another message : openwith-file-handler: Opened KLOCKA6.JPG in external program.

Comment: That's a different problem: you should open another question for that problem and provide all relevant information.